# How to convert Rust strings to UTF-16?

Tags: string, rust, utf-16

> Editor's note: This code example is from a version of Rust prior to 1.0 and is not valid Rust 1.0 code, but the answers still contain valuable information.

I want to pass a string literal to a Windows API. Many Windows functions use UTF-16 as the string encoding while Rust's native strings are UTF-8.

I know Rust has [utf16_units()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/str/trait.StrSlice.html#tymethod.utf16_units) to produce a UTF-16 character iterator, but I don't know how to use that function to produce a UTF-16 string with zero as last character.

I'm producing the UTF-16 string like this, but I am sure there is a better method to produce it:

```
extern "system" {
    pub fn MessageBoxW(hWnd: int, lpText: *const u16, lpCaption: *const u16, uType: uint) -> int;
}

pub fn main() {
    let s1 = [
        'H' as u16, 'e' as u16, 'l' as u16, 'l' as u16, 'o' as u16, 0 as u16,
    ];
    unsafe {
        MessageBoxW(0, s1.as_ptr(), 0 as *const u16, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Rust 1.8+

[`str::encode_utf16`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.encode_utf16) is the stable iterator of UTF-16 values.

You just need to use `collect()` on that iterator to construct `Vec<u16>` and then `push(0)` on that vector:

```
pub fn main() {
    let s = "Hello";

    let mut v: Vec<u16> = s.encode_utf16().collect();
    v.push(0);
}
```

#### Rust 1.0+

`str::utf16_units()` / `str::encode_utf16` is unstable. The alternative is to either switch to nightly (a viable option if you're writing a program, not a library) or to use an external crate like [encoding](https://crates.io/crates/encoding):

```
extern crate encoding;

use std::slice;

use encoding::all::UTF_16LE;
use encoding::{Encoding, EncoderTrap};

fn main() {
    let s = "Hello";

    let mut v: Vec<u8> = UTF_16LE.encode(s, EncoderTrap::Strict).unwrap();
    v.push(0); v.push(0);
    let s: &[u16] = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(v.as_ptr() as *const _, v.len()/2) };
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

(or you can use [`from_raw_parts_mut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts_mut.html) if you want a `&mut [u16]`).

However, in this particular example you have to be careful with endianness because `UTF_16LE` encoding gives you a vector of bytes representing `u16`'s in little endian byte order, while the `from_raw_parts` trick allows you to "view" the vector of bytes as a slice of `u16`'s in your platform's byte order, which may as well be big endian. Using a crate like [`byteorder`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/byteorder) may be helpful here if you want complete portability.

[This](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/37k1ij/converting_str_to_utf16/) discussion on Reddit may also be helpful.

Comment: wow, that works! thanks. Previously i use let mut v = s.utf16_units().collect::<u16>(); but the code failed to compile.

Comment: @GigihAjiIbrahim, it failed to compile because `collect()`'s type argument should be target collection, not element type. `collect::<Vec<u16>>()` would have worked too.

Answer (score 5):

## Rust 1.46+

For static UTF-16 strings, the [`utf16_lit`](https://crates.io/crates/utf16_lit) crate provides an easy to use macro to do this at compile time:

```rust
use utf16_lit::utf16_null;

fn main() {
    let s = &utf16_null!("Hello");
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using literals, you can use the `w` macro from `windows-sys`: https://docs.rs/windows-sys/latest/windows_sys/macro.w.html

```
use windows_sys::w;

MessageBoxW(0, w!("Hello"), 0 as *const u16, 0);
```

Comment: I think in current rust version, this is the best answer if we dealing with windows API. Never thought that my question from 9 year ago still useful 