# Writing a &str to the console using winapi goes wrong when using CString

Tags: winapi, console, rust, ffi

I want to write a `&str` to the console using [`WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputattribute) from [the winapi crate](https://crates.io/crates/winapi). I only have an u8 array which will be passed from the `std::io::Write` implementation of a struct to my winapi code.

The following does not work correctly as I see colored cells instead of text.

```
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::str;
use winapi::um::wincon::{
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo, WriteConsoleOutputAttribute, CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO, COORD,
};
use winapi::um::winnt::HANDLE;

pub fn write_char_buffer(handle: HANDLE, buf: &[u8]) {
    // get buffer info
    let csbi = get_console_screen_buffer_info();

    // get string from u8[] and parse it to an c_str
    let data = str::from_utf8(buf).unwrap();
    let c_str = CString::new(data).unwrap();
    let ptr: *const u16 = (c_str.as_ptr() as *const u16);

    // get current position
    let current_pos = COORD {
        X: csbi.dwCursorPosition.X,
        Y: csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y,
    };

    let mut cells_written: u32 = 0;

    // write to console
    unsafe {
        WriteConsoleOutputAttribute(
            handle,
            ptr,
            data.len() as u32,
            current_pos,
            &mut cells_written,
        );
    }
}

pub fn get_console_screen_buffer_info() -> CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO {
    let output_handle = get_output_handle();
    let mut csbi = CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO::empty();
    let success;

    unsafe { success = GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(output_handle, &mut csbi) }

    if success == 0 {
        panic!("Cannot get console screen buffer info");
    }

    csbi
}
```

I think that it is going wrong with the `CString` and the pointer. See this [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4c71216a8e24ecf86ff39beeca013848&version=undefined&mode=undefined) for the code.

**[Update](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b15c1ca663f7bfaaa552370829b1b00e&version=stable&mode=debug)**

Rust strings are utf8 while winapi strings are utf16. So I convert the utf8 array to utf16 String but the same output is shown, just collored cells in the console without text:

```
let utf8 = str::from_utf8(buf).unwrap();
let utf16: Vec<u16> = utf8.encode_utf16().collect();
let utf_string = String::from_utf16(&utf16).unwrap();
let c_str = CString::new(utf_string).unwrap();
```

Comment: I have read that, but I see that unwrap should be called on the same line when CString is created. I will take a look.

Comment: Okay, I have bound it to a local variable. This does not seem to work. The pointer has an value withs is `"0x1c57fa2c0a0"`. Also, the cstring is not `ERR`. I don't see characters in the console but a colored cel for each character.

The links you send are not applying to my situation. I can explain why my question is not duplicate: 

1: I am not trying to convert the cstring back. 
2: the pointer is  not null 
3: this is not the case, I have fixed the code and it still results in an error. 
4: Also the last link does not apply to my problem, unfortunately.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to convert Rust strings to UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25197315/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: A Rust string is UTF-8. Windows expects UTF-16.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this could be the problem but there is no diffrence in the output. This is how I convert u8 array to String is this right? `let utf8 = str::from_utf8(buf).unwrap();
    let utf16: Vec<u16> = utf8.encode_utf16().collect();
    let utf_string = String::from_utf16(&utf16).unwrap();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to write a `&str` to the console using `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`

That's not what that function does. `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute` sets *character attributes*: things like background color, foreground color, underline. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers#span-idwin32characterattributesspanspan-idwin32characterattributesspancharacter-attributes) has a (more) complete list.

To write text to the console, use `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` after converting it to UTF-16.

Comment: Thanks that could be the solution. The discription of 'WriteConsoleOutputAttribute' is: Copies a number of character attributes to consecutive cells of a console screen buffer, beginning at a specified location.' I didn't see the word 'attribute' I will give it a try.

Comment: It works now tanks, I use the function `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA`.