# Create a popup in Rust using Windows APIs

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I would like to create a dialog box or popup in Rust in a similar fashion to [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/x83z1d9f(v=vs.84)).

I'm struggling to find documentation on the Windows APIs for this. The closest I've found so far is [the `CreateDialogA` macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialoga) ([Rust winapi equivalent](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.6/winapi/um/winuser/index.html)).

I've found some things on it such as [Creating a New Dialog Box (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/windows/creating-a-new-dialog-box?view=vs-2017), but most of it is not applicable to a Rust project.

Perhaps [dialoge template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/dialogex-resource) is relevant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## main.rs

```
extern crate winapi;

use std::ptr::null_mut as NULL;
use winapi::um::winuser;

fn main() {
    let l_msg: Vec<u16> = "Wassa wassa wassup\0".encode_utf16().collect();
    let l_title: Vec<u16> = "\u{20BF}itconnect\0".encode_utf16().collect();

    unsafe {
        winuser::MessageBoxW(NULL(), l_msg.as_ptr(), l_title.as_ptr(), winuser::MB_OK | winuser::MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
}
```

This uses the [MessageBoxW function](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.6/winapi/um/winuser/fn.MessageBoxW.html).

The argument `winuser::MB_OK` can be `winuser::MB_OK`, `winuser::MB_OKCANCEL`, `winuser::MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE`, `winuser::MB_YESNOCANCEL`, `winuser::MB_YESNO`, `winuser::MB_RETRYCANCEL` or `winuser::MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE`.

The argument `winuser::MB_ICONINFORMATION` can be `winuser::MB_ICONHAND`, `winuser::MB_ICONQUESTION`, `winuser:: MB_ICONEXCLAMATION` or `winuser::MB_ICONASTERISK`.

## Cargo.toml should include:

```
[dependencies.winapi]
version = "0.3"
features = ["winuser"]
```

[image: popup]

Comment: BTW, as_ptr is gemerating stome weird results for me. sometimes there are loads of strange kanji and stuff popping up.

Comment: @DerpMarine you are almost certainly either running into the analog of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235267/conversion-between-a-rust-str-and-fficstring-and-back-again-partially-corrupts) or you've forgotten your trailing `\0`, or you aren't [converting to UTF-16 correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197315/how-to-convert-rust-strings-to-utf-16).

Comment: I fixed it, by pushing \0 onto the vec. `.push(0);`. (It's user input that I'm dealing with.) Thanks!