# PdhAddCounterW - no rules expected this token in macro call

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, performancecounter

I am writing a program to collect Performance Counter. The program is written in `Rust` and uses the `windows` crate.

Below is the relevant portion of the code.

```rust
let mut query = 0;
PdhOpenQueryW(None, 0, &mut query);
let query_path = CString::new("\\Processor(0)\\% Processor Time");
let mut counter = 0;
PdhAddCounterW(
    query,
    w!(query_path.as_ptr()),
    0,
    &mut counter,
);
```

The compiler message is:

```
error: no rules expected the token `query_path`
  --> src\main.rs:12:16
   |
12 |             w!(query_path.as_ptr()),
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
   |
note: while trying to match meta-variable `$s:literal`
  --> C:\Users\T9SAU2\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\windows-0.48.0\src\core\strings\literals.rs:12:6
```

I want to explain my analysis and understanding on `String` in Rust, please let me know where I am going wrong.

When I navigate to `C:\Users\T9SAU2\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\windows-0.48.0\src\core\strings\literals.rs:12:6`, the relevant code and comment is -

```rust
/// A literal UTF-16 wide string with a trailing null terminator.
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! w {
    ($s:literal) => {{
        const INPUT: &[u8] = $s.as_bytes();
        const OUTPUT_LEN: usize = $crate::core::utf16_len(INPUT) + 1;
```

The input is supposed to be a UTF-16 null-terminated string.

The function signature for `PdhAddCounterW()` is:

```rust
pub unsafe fn PdhAddCounterW<P0>(
    hquery: isize,
    szfullcounterpath: P0,
    dwuserdata: usize,
    phcounter: *mut isize
) -> u32
where
    P0: IntoParam<PCWSTR>,
```

Link - https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Performance/fn.PdhAddCounterW.html

The argument `szfullcounterpath` is of type `IntoParam\<PCWSTR\>`. `PCWSTR` is defined as:

```rust
pub struct PCWSTR(pub *const u16);
```

> A pointer to a constant null-terminated string of 16-bit Unicode characters.

A `String` in Rust is not null-terminated and is UTF-8. The underlying definition is:

```rust
pub struct String {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
}
```

Basically, a vector of unsigned 8 bits. This will not work.

The argument `szfullcounterpath` should be a pointer to a null-terminated vector of `u16`.

`str` is another type and is valid string slices. This type has an interesting function `encode_utf16`. Another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197315/) confirms the same.

However, when I use the following, I still get the same error:

```rust
let mut v: Vec<u16> = query_path.encode_utf16().collect();
v.push(0);
```

I referred to the blog [Rust # 8: Strings](https://dev.to/cthutu/rust-8-strings-53o). From here, I learned about `OsString` and `CString`.

Rust document on `OsString` states:

> On Windows, strings are often arbitrary sequences of non-zero 16-bit values, interpreted as UTF-16 when it is valid to do so.
> ...
> ... on Windows, where strings are 16-bit value based as just discussed, strings are also actually stored as a sequence of 8-bit values, encoded in a less-strict variant of UTF-8. This is useful to understand when handling capacity and length values.

The `OsString` on Windows is UTF-16, but doesn't mention anything about null termination. Also, it is stored as a sequence of `u8`, hence I am not sure if it can be used without manipulating it to `u16` and adding null termination.

`CString` is a type representing an owned, C-compatible, null-terminated string with no `nul` bytes in the middle. It is a Box type, hence a smart pointer, but an array of `u8`. A smart pointer can be converted to a raw pointer, but still this needs to be changed to `u16`. If I have to use this, I need to iterate over box type and use shifting to convert from `u8` to `u16`.

I believe the easiest option is string slice, yet I receive the same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: *"OsString on windows is UTF-16"* - It isn't. `OsString` is *always* UTF-8, but being relaxed to allow encoding of unmatched surrogate pairs. There is no UTF-16 string type in all of Rust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`w!`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/macro.w.html) macro can only be applied to string literals. Your code should thus read:

```rust
// ...
let mut counter = 0;
PdhAddCounterW(
    query,
    w!("\\Processor(0)\\% Processor Time"),
    0,
    &mut counter,
);
```

---

If you do need to construct a UTF-16 encoded string at run time and thus cannot use the `w!` macro, there are several options. Since Rust doesn't provide a string type that uses UTF-16 encoding, they all follow pretty much the same pattern:

- Construct the string (using Rust's native UTF-8 encoding)
- Transcode from UTF-8 to UTF-16
- (Optionally) append a zero terminator

While you can do that manually, e.g.

```rust
let utf16 = text.encode_utf16().chain(once(0)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

it is far more convenient to use the tools offered by the `windows` crate instead. All string handling is centered around the [`HSTRING`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/struct.HSTRING.html) type, that can be constructed from just about any Rust string type, and also passed into functions that expect a `IntoParam<PCWSTR>`.

If `query_path` is constructed at run time, you can change your code to read

```rust
let mut query = 0;
PdhOpenQueryW(None, 0, &mut query);
let query_path = String::from("\\Processor(0)\\% Processor Time");
let mut counter = 0;
PdhAddCounterW(
    query,
    &HSTRING::from(&query_path),
    0,
    &mut counter,
);
```

All `impl From`'s for `HSTRING` translate from UTF-8 to UTF-16, and append a zero terminator.

Comment: I have list of performance counter query that needs to be executed. Hence I need PdhAddCounterW to accept path from variable. Hence, I cannot use hardcoded query. However, thanks for pointing out the macro definition. Instead of macro, I need to use IntoParam\<PCWSTR\>. I realize my mistake now.

Comment: @TusharSaurabh If you need a list of performance counters, then just store them in a `const` array, using the `w!` macro for each entry. `IntoParam<PCWSTR>` is provided for convenience only. Client code never needs to create those types. It's just there to be able to pass a number of things that can be converted into a `PCWSTR` (which the native API call expects).

Comment: I am trying to create a solution for monitoring web applications. The application landscape includes IIS, Windows Service, processes and batch jobs. IIS has multiple apppools on different server. Hence I have decided to create a config file that will provide name of the processes and apppools. I am using multiple counters and these have instance object. For example -  HTTP Service Request Queues performance counter can count queue size for each apppool. Hence performance counter path cannot be constant. It is dynamically generated based on apppool names and processes that I am tracking.